# ¿Como esconder un elemento input al seleccionar un radiobutton en mvc asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Soy nuevo en este entorno de trabajo utilizando aspnet y me gustaría saber si hay forma de mostrar un input al momento de seleccionar un elemento en el radio button sin tratar de usar javascript.

> Método creado en el controlador llamado tg04Personas

```
public string radio(FormCollection frm)
    {
        string genderradio = frm["personaTipo"].ToString();
        if (genderradio == "natural")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/tg04Personas/CreateNatural");
            return "";
        }
        else if (genderradio == "juridica")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/tg04Personas/Create");
            return "";
        }
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/tg04Personas");
            return "";
        }
    }
```

> Vista Creada

```
@model PiramideWeb.Models.tg04Personas
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Choose";
}
<h2>Selccione el tipo de Persona</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("radio", "tg04Personas", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.personaTipo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col- md-2" }) <br />
    <div class="col-md-10">
        Natural @Html.RadioButton("personaTipo", "natural",true, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
        Juridica @Html.RadioButton("personaTipo", "juridica", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
        Extranjera @Html.RadioButton("personaTipo", "extranjera", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })
    </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Seleccionar" />
}
```

> Duda
>   - Se puede llamar al método sin tener que dar clic en el botón submit de manera dinámica, o no se puede realizar dicha acción. Agradezco su atención prestada.

Comment: Hola Ecst, bienvenido. Esta pregunta se considera muy amplia porque has de haberlo intentado primero. Con intentar, me refiero a investigar por tu cuenta, y tener pruebas de codigo. Con eso, nos explicas qué estas probando y nos dices qué errores o problemas concretos tienes. mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo el codigo y el ejemplo en [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqvQgd)

```
<label for="show"><span>(Mostrar)</span></label>
<input type=radio id="show" name="group">
<label for="hide"><span>(Ocultar)</span></label>    
<input type=radio id="hide" name="group">
<input id="content" placeholder="Saludos">

input {
    display:none;
}

span#content {
    display:none;
}

input#show:checked ~ span#content{
  display:block;
}

input#show:checked ~ label#id1{
  display:none;
}
input#show:checked ~ label#id2{
  display:block;
}

input#hide:checked ~ label#id2{
  display:none;
}
input#hide:checked ~ label#id1{
  display:block;
}
input#hide:checked ~ span#content{
    display:none;
}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Directamente por javascript lo veo mas sencillo:

```
<input type="radio" id="rdBtn" onclick="if(document.getElementById('rdBtn').checked===true){document.getElementById('texto').style.display ='';}else{document.getElementById('texto').style.display = 'none';}"/>

<input type="text" id="texto" style="display:none"/>
```